# CSV Dataset Float issue in Python

Tags: python, csv, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with this dataset at below measurements.csv

https://www.kaggle.com/anderas/car-consume/data

It has values inside like this: 21,5 but floating definition must be like that 21.5 Therefore, Python says, **"ValueError: could not convert string to float: '21,5'"**

My codes are as these,

```
# get data ready
data = pd.read_csv('measurements.csv')
data.shape
# split out features and label
X = data.iloc[:, :-5].values
y = data.iloc[:, -4]
# map category to binary
y = np.where(y == 'E10', 1, 0)
enc = OneHotEncoder()
```

Second Question:
I also want to use its another columns which has string values or null (empty) how should I transform them to my input shape?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell read_csv what the character for decimal point is:

```
data = pd.read_csv('measurements.csv', decimal=',')
```

From https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: My Dataset has empty cells, 'AC rain', 'AC', 'rain', 'sun' etc. How can I add them to X variable? I want to create one X variable to use direct input

Comment: @Karamel Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In read_csv, you can speciify decimal values as

```
data = pd.read_csv('measurements.csv', decimal=",")
```

Comment: My Dataset has empty cells, 'AC rain', 'AC', 'rain', 'sun' etc. How can I add them to X variable? I want to create one X variable to use direct input